# remove xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" when using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

how can I remove the xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" when using DataContractSerializer.

this is what I'm getting:

```
<ProfileModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Email>wolverine@wolverine.com</Email>
  <FirstName>wolverine</FirstName>
  <ID>ty1002225</ID>
  <LastName>wolverine3</LastName>
  <PhoneNumber>66332214477</PhoneNumber>
  <SourceSystem>TY</SourceSystem>
</ProfileModel>
```

I want to get something like this:

```
<ProfileModel>
      <Email>wolverine@wolverine.com</Email>
      <FirstName>wolverine</FirstName>
      <ID>ty1002225</ID>
      <LastName>wolverine3</LastName>
      <PhoneNumber>66332214477</PhoneNumber>
      <SourceSystem>TY</SourceSystem>
    </ProfileModel>
```

this is my model:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CRMProfileModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to avoid to use string replace to remove it.

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061839/3383479

Comment: @Inanikian the Op is using DataContractSerializer, not XmlSerializer

Comment: @rcadaoas did you ever find a way to do it without string replace? I spent some time researching this, but from everything I found, it seems not possible.

Comment: @CrnaStena, I still went for the string replace approach unfortunately.

Comment: You need to use a custom serializer.

Comment: Can you add to your post your implementation of serialization CRMProfileModel class with DataContractSerializer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing namespaces serializing with DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901937/removing-namespaces-serializing-with-datacontractserializer)

Answer (score -1):

**how can I remove the xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" when using DataContractSerializer.**

1. hii **Romeo**... i also tried for couple of hours to remove xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".
2. Finally i found my best,hope it will helpful

   public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MessageResponse value)

{

```
 var messageresponse =new CRMProfileModel(){.....};
DataContractSerializer doc = new  DataContractSerializer(messageresponse.GetType());  
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 dcs.WriteObject(ms, messageresponse); 
var i = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()); 
var r = i.Replace("xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"","");
var ss = new XmlDocument(); 
ss.LoadXml(r);
return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, ss.DocumentElement, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

}

Comment: the OP asks for a solution other than 'replace': **I'm trying to avoid to use string replace to remove it.**