# Attribute XmlNamespaceDeclarations is ignored during XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces

I try to serialize an object with custom namespaces. This is how the class looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("Root", Namespace = "myNamespace")]
public partial class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        this.Xmlns.Add(string.Empty, "myNamespace");
    }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations()]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Xmlns = null;
}
```

And here is the code to serialize it:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
```

The expected result is

```
<Root xmlns="myNamespace" />
```

However it still has xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="myNamespace" />
```

When I serialize using `serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, obj.Xmlns)`, the result is correct.

Why does serializer ignore that `XmlNamespaceDeclarations` attribute? Shouldn't it automatically take the namespace declarations from it? How can I define namespaces inside serialized class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does serializer ignore that XmlNamespaceDeclarations attribute?
>   Shouldn't it automatically take the namespace declarations from it?

Actually, what the `Serializer` does is **not** *ignoring* your `XmlNamespaceDeclarations` but *adding* them into the default, internal, `XmlWriter namespaces`.

By default, there are already some `prefixes-namespaces pairs` (or I would simply call `namespaces` for simplicity for the rests of this answer) embedded to the `XmlWriter`. They are what you see:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" //note the lovely pairs here
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Thus, if you use `XmlWriter`, you got to bear with its `default namespaces` which unfortunately are not exposed to the outside user. And, to make things "worse" (actually, not that worse, but I try to put this in context), it somehow does not allow you to do anything with it.

The only `XmlWriter` property that got something to do with `namespace` is [NamespaceHandling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.namespacehandling(v=vs.110).aspx), which can only be set to either removing *duplicate* `namespaces` or retaining them. Which means, the property would only be of any use if you have somehow - rather magically - declared `duplicate namespaces` for your `serializable class`:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Nevertheless, `XmlWriter` still have some "good" things that you can omit the `XmlDeclaration` by setting:

```
OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```

when you create your `XmlWriterSettings` and use the settings to initialize your `XmlWriter`

In short, we cannot hope `XmlWriter` to do good things to us by removing its `default namespaces` - it simply can't.

And thus, we must to the `Serializer` to get the solution

---

> How can I define namespaces inside serialized class?

Believe it or not, it is *exactly like what you already did*!

The [overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize(v=vs.110).aspx) method [Serialize(XmlWriter, Object, XmlSerializerNamespaces)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h(v=vs.110).aspx) is designed just for that purpose. When you call it:

```
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, obj.Xmlns);
```

It *replaces* the `default namespaces + your namespaces` with *only* `your namespaces`

If you use `Serialize(XmlWriter, Object)` overload, what the `Serializer` does is to take all the `namespaces` in the `XmlWriter` as well as in the `Object` and then write XML file. Thus you got all the `namespaces` there: **the default and yours**.

This is probably because `XmlWriter` also (internally) apply [XmlNamespaceScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacescope(v=vs.110).aspx) to be `XmlNamespaceScope.All` which you - again - can do nothing about it.

But when you use `Serialize(XmlWriter, Object, XmlSerializerNamespaces)`, you actually tell the `Serializer` to only use `XmlSerializerNamespaces` that you specify. And so, it does the right thing!

In other words, what you did is already an "official" way for getting the namespaces that you want in the `Xml` file.

That note aside, you could also put multiple `namespaces` to your XML file as you wish by simply using as many times `Xmlns.Add(prefix, ns)` as you want.

Thus, you already did the right thing for your purpose. I merely trying to explain why it is so.

Comment: OK, that can replace namespaces. So how does that _remove_ the namespaces from the output? I don't want them or need them.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do anything special to your serialized class - its a known issue. Various workarounds have been suggested here:

[XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces)

[How to serialize an object to XML without getting xmlns="..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-without-getting-xmlns)

[xml serialization - remove namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061106/xml-serialization-remove-namespace)

Comment: But I don't need anything special. I just want that namespaces declared inside the class to take effect.