# Add Namespace to an xml root node c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml and I want to add

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../test/Schemas/test.xsd"

to xml root element programmatically in c# so that the xml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../test/Schemas/test.xsd" >
<value></value>
.
.

<root>
```

what I tried

> doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
>   doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../test/Schemas/test.xsd");

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417590/attribute-xmlnamespacedeclarations-is-ignored-during-xml-serialization) may possibly help to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create the *xsi* attribute using the [CreateAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2zzesf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and then adding this attribute to the root element like:

```
XmlAttribute xsiAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xsiAttr.Value = "../../../../test/Schemas/test.xsd";
doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(xsiAttr);
```