# How to add xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation to Serializer

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I build an XML Document which needs to be validated against a xsd file. Thus I need a reference to the xsd file in the root element of the xml. So far I use this C# Code:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myspecialtype));
XmlSerializerNamespaces MainNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
MainNamespace.Add("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
MainNamespace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\myxmlfile.xml"))
{
    w.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"utils/somexsl.xsl\"");
    ser.Serialize(w, LeBigObject, HauptNs);
}
```

The resulting Xml begins like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="utils/somexsl.xsl"?>
<caddy-xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlVersion="03.07.00">
```

but I need this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="utils/somexsl.xsl"?>
<caddy-xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlVersion="03.07.00" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="utils/theveryimportant.xsd">
```

I came across "CreateAttribute" here: [Add Namespace to an xml root node c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146718/) but I can't put it together with the Serializer. Thank you!

Comment: See [XML Serialization Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27533862/3744182) which shows how to add both `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` and `xsi:schemaLocation`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was pointed to the solution here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e43585c6-181b-4449-8806-b07f82681a2a/how-to-include-xsinonamespaceschemalocation-in-the-xml?forum=asmxandxml

I added this to my class:

```
[XmlAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string attr = "utils/theveryimportant.xsd";
```

and it works.